# Philips Hue REST api/nupnp : the answer is empty

Tags: api, rest, upnp, bridge, philips-hue

I just want discover the IP address of my bridge and I have some problems with www.meethue.com/api/nupnp

In fact, yesterday, when I made my request, I had got an answer like this:

```
["id":..., "internalipaddress":...]
```

All worked great.

But, this morning, I restart the same request and.. I have just this :

```
[ ]
```

However, my bridge works because I can go to the same IP address that I found yesterday and I can change my lamps states.

Do you have an idea to solve my problem ?

Comment: Have you read the philips documentation? They have a Hue Bridge Discovery Guide (behind a login, of course). Alternatively, have you tried UPnP since it should be supported?

Comment: Yes, I read the philips documentation. My solution is their second part no ? For UPnP, I didn't try yet because I think that I don't really understand how I could do it. So, if you have example of UPnP, I could try with this solution.

Comment: Are you saying the Discovery Guide gives no examples of the UPnP method? Anyway, can't help with the meethue.com/api/nupnp discovery as Philips doesn't say how it works (not in public anyway). With UpnP, your first step would be to find a "UPnP universal control point" app and make sure the bridge shows up as a UpnP device -- then you can think about implementing the discovery yourself. You don't mention your platform or language so it's hard to give suggestions, but on linux gupnp-tools package contains  a suitable `gupnp-universal-cp` application and libgssdp is a good discovery library

Comment: I work on a Watch app with swift.

Answer (score 2):

For the /nupnp discovery to work your application has to be on the same network as your bridge.

If the device you are running your application on connects to the internet through another network (e.g. a phone on 3G instead of Wifi or you have a VPN enabled on your laptop) then you will not be able to find the bridge through /nupnp and therefore get the empty list [].

For a solution to discover your bridge you could try a few things:

1) Since you mention Watch and Swift I guess you are doing something with iOS. Maybe you can use the Philips iOS SDK for discovery?

2) Do an IP scan like suggested in the Philips documentation. Be aware to keep you scan limited to the correct subnet!

3) UPnP, this is generally tricky to get right which is why I am mentioning it last. But there might be libraries to help you with that.

For my personal projects I tend to use a combination of /nupnp and IP scan to discover bridges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was on the same WiFi all the time and sometimes it doesn't work with this /nupnp. I tried to use the iOS SDK but I think that watchOS isn't supported, you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529055/ios-sdk-hue-philips-with-swift). Actually, I use the /nupnp and I added on my phone app a textField to put manually my IP value if /nupnp doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the empty array result you got, I'd say you reached the Hue site just fine, but it could not reach back to your hub to retrieve its id or ip address. This could be because you are not logged into the hue portal, or it could be caused by any number of ways an http request can fail.

If I were you, I'd 1)Set up a static ip for the Hue Hub in my router, so it doesn't change because of DHCP and 2)Store its ip using NSUserDefaults anytime you DO get the value. That way, if you get an empty array, you can fall back to the previously-stored value by reading NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I can write my static IP during development time but after, I have to find automatically the IP address. I don't want that a user have to fix his own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same tonight, and it's not the first time. Since I wasted 30 good minutes trying to figure it out, here it is:
look up for MAC adrees like 00:17:88:40:XX:XX in your router/system monitor/ARP table.

Then after you get the correct IP, set this ip-address by hand in the application you have.
Bingo, the device works just fine, and indeed it was 'https://discovery.meethue.com/' which doesn't work and returns an empty data structure shown by the browser as [].

Unfortunately I could not set the PHUE DHCP to private with my ZYXEL router, another badly overly documented device, which lacks the fundamental features at the forefront...